# All terminals in i3 WM share the same input

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, window-manager, i3

I am trying out i3 tiling window manager on Ubuntu 20.04.

All terminals started with `$mod+Enter` share the same input: i.e. if I type something on one terminal, the same gets printed on another. This is not an expected behavoir :)

What's strange, if I start `terminator` with `$mod+d`, I do not see `terminator` in `pstree` output, and resulting terminal behaves the same. Turns out they are all `terminator`s - seeing this by terminator-specific interface.

Used just `sudo apt-get install i3` to install i3.

```
$ i3 --version
i3 version 4.17.1 (2019-08-30) © 2009 Michael Stapelberg and contributors
```

How can I get them working separately without echoing input on all of the terminals?

Comment: Looks like this is a `terminator` specific problem. If I start `gnome-terminal` with `$mod+d`, there is no echo onto other terminals.

Comment: I think it does not make sense to run a tiling terminal inside a tiling WM, so I selected `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal.wrapper` as a default terminal with `sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator`.

But the problem with terminator remains unsolved - maybe someone likes it for a reason other then tiling?